# ValueError: x and y must be the same size in Matplotlib

Tags: python

If I want to make a scatter plot with matplotlib like this:

```
import matplotlib as plt
x = [float(1) for x in xrange(2)]
y = [float(2) for x in xrange(2)]
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I always get the above Error.
But if I do as so instead:

```
import matplotlib as plt
x = [1.0, 1.0]
y = [2.0, 2.0]
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

it works. Why is that?

Comment: use a 3rd variable in your `for x in ...`, for instance `for i in...` otherwise x is overwritten when you generate your y varaible

Comment: As would be clear if you actually e.g. `print x, y` to see whether they're what you expected.

Comment: I am tempted to do +1 as well as -1. +1, because it *would* be a good question if it was not so very easy to find out what really happens here. As it is so trivial to find out (by `printìng the variables), I tend to do -1. I think I just do nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting `x` when assigning `y`

```
x = [float(1) for x in xrange(2)] # x = [1, 1]
y = [float(2) for x in xrange(2)] # x = 1; y = [2, 2]
                  ^
```

Instead of using `x` use `_` (the "don't care variable in python" as suggested by @kroolik)

```
x = [float(1) for _ in xrange(2)]
y = [float(2) for _ in xrange(2)]
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that although this is best practice, Python 3.x's list-comp's no longer leak scope - but it's definitely a "gotcha" in 2.x :)

Comment: Good practice, if you are not going to use the value returned by `xrange` is to use `_` for loop iteration values. One does not sanely use `_` for variable name except for `gettext` where it is a convention.

Comment: is has to be `x = [1.0, 1.0]` at the top